# run and stop perl script from cron job - cpanel

Tags: perl, cron

My path to the perl script is

```
public_html/Staging/ff/sendmail.pl
```

The command to run the perl script in cron job cpanel is

```
cd /public_html/Staging/ff; perl sendmail.pl >/dev/null
```

[image]

is set to every 1 min, which is not working. What could be the issue? And how to stop the same process

Comment: Your path to Perl script is `/public_html/Staging/ff` or `public_html/Staging/ff`. There is subtle difference between them. First one is `absolute path` second one is `relative path` w.r.t your current directory.They may be same or may not be so, please verify the exact location of your Perl script and try to run it manually first.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. relative path actually worked fine.

Comment: How do i stop this process?

Comment: `kill` typically. Or amend your `crontab` again.

Comment: could not find the way to kill my process. Its running still :(

Comment: check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313033/how-can-i-see-stop-current-running-crontab-tasks)

Comment: seriously couldnt find way to stop.  do i have to add new cron job as just `kill`? even though if i delete my cron job, its still running

Answer (score 1):

While my answer is extremely late to the party;

As of CPanel 102.*.* (and for various releases before this) The reason the cronjob does not run is that CPanel crons do not "queue" commands; you can only run one command at a time per cron.

Therefore:

```
 perl /public_html/Staging/ff/sendmail.pl >/dev/null
```

will work as your cron command, using absolute pathing and removing the need to change directory.

Comment: In cron, sometimes I need to change directories so that relative paths in the program work out, so I do something like `cd /some/dir && perl script.pl`. It's also useful for directories that might exist, and when they do, I want to run the job.

Comment: @briandfoy that sort of thing (if statements and absolute pathing) should be handled within the perl script rather than running `if` queries in the cron command queue.

Comment: @briandfoy Or, if you don't want to query these things within the perl script then you can wrap the perl script inside a bash file which contains these commands, and then the cronjob only calls the bash file. Note the cronjob should only execute one command. I don't know if this is a cron-specific limitation or if this is a CPanel security limitation

Comment: Well, unless it's not the perl script's job to control everything for you. A shell script could set it up and then be the cron command, but the that has to live somewhere. But, if the directory doesn't exist (isn't mounted, for example), you can't very well use the wrapper. It's just as easy to do it in cron.

Comment: @briandfoy it's only easy if the cron accepts command queues, but the cPanel cron interface doesn't. As I say, I don't know if this is a cron specific limitation or if this is a cPanel limitation.